# How can I simplify converting errors into strings multiple times in a function?

Tags: rust

Is there any way to simplify this code?

```
fn parse(line: &str) -> Result<(usize, f64), String> {
    let mut it = line.split_whitespace();
    let n  = it.next().ok_or("Invalid line")?;
    let n = n.parse::<usize>().map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
    let f = it.next().ok_or("Invalid line")?;
    let f = f.parse::<f64>().map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
    Ok((n, f))
}

fn main() {       
    println!("Results: {:?}", parse("5 17.2").unwrap())
}
```

In real code I need to parse 4 values in line,
and it is boring to write `.map_err(|e| e.to_string())`

As I understand it, it is impossible to implement `std::convert::From` for `ParseIntError` / `ParseFloatError` -> `String`, because none of the types are defined in my code, am I right?

I see one way to simplify this code:

```
fn econv<E: ToString>(e: E) -> String {
    e.to_string()
}
```

and use `.map_err(econv)`. Are there any other options to simplify my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a not too terrible option would simply be to create a function to abstract over the repetition:

```
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::iter::Iterator;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn parse_next<'a, Target, T>(it: &mut T) -> Result<Target, String>
    where
        T: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
        Target: FromStr,
        <Target as FromStr>::Err: Display
{
    it.next().ok_or("Invalid line")?.parse::<Target>().map_err(|e| e.to_string())
}

fn parse(line: &str) -> Result<(usize, f64), String> {
    let mut it = line.split_whitespace();
    Ok((parse_next(&mut it)?, parse_next(&mut it)?))
}

fn main() {       
    println!("Results: {:?}", parse("5 17.2").unwrap())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd introduce a dedicated error type. If *needed*, I'd then transform the error into a string once after that:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate quick_error;

quick_error! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum Error {
        InvalidLine {}
        Int(err: std::num::ParseIntError) {
            from()
        }
        Float(err: std::num::ParseFloatError) {
            from()
        }
    }
}

fn parse_inner(line: &str) -> Result<(usize, f64), Error> {
    let mut it = line.split_whitespace();
    let n = it.next().ok_or(Error::InvalidLine)?;
    let n = n.parse()?;
    let f = it.next().ok_or(Error::InvalidLine)?;
    let f = f.parse()?;
    Ok((n, f))
}

fn parse(line: &str) -> Result<(usize, f64), String> {
    parse_inner(line).map_err(|e| e.to_string())
}

fn main() {
    println!("Results: {:?}", parse("5 17.2").unwrap())
}
```